# Giving notification to another class with NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

So my goal is to deliver a notification to another class with using `NSNotificationCenter`, I also want to pass `object` with the notification to the other `class`, how should I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must first register a notification name

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startLocating:) name:@"ForceUpdateLocation" object:nil]; // don't forget the ":"
```

And then post a notification with a dictionary of parameters

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ForceUpdateLocation" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1,2,3,4,5" forKey:@"categories_ids"]];
```

and the method will be

```
- (void)startLocating:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
}
```

Comment: How I access the userInfo in my method which is called?

Comment: @notme - isn't is better if you post and register for the same notification names ?

Comment: @Vince, you are right, I did some copy/paste error. I'll correct in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Just call any method for posting notifications as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), for instance :

to post a notification :

```
-(void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName
                     object:(id)notificationSender
                   userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

where `userInfo` is a dictionary containing useful objects.

On the other side to register for notifications :

```
-(void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver
           selector:(SEL)notificationSelector
               name:(NSString *)notificationName
             object:(id)notificationSender;
```

You could also check Apple's [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).