# iPhone - After facebook login, status of UISwitch is not setting to 'On' in -(void)fbDidLogin method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, uiswitch

I have implemented Facebook login and checking the status of my access token in

```
-(void)fbDidLogin
```

Now, I have a `UITableView` where I have a toggle `Button` as `UISwitch` which turns on if I have got an access token. The problem is, when I get an access token

```
-(void)fbDidLogin
```

method gets called. Here, I'm setting the switch of toggle button on by calling

```
[self.switch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

but its not happening. when I go back and open that page again, its showing the right status but not when I set it in `fbDidLogin`. Any guesses why this is happening?

For facebook authentication, it goes outside of the application and comes back, maybe thats why its happening? but I'm calling a webservice from `fbDidLogin` and its working fine.

code is simple

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {    
    [self.switch setOn:YES animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: maintain flag in appdelegate when facebook login or logout and now add code in view will appear method if flag true switch is on and vice-versa

Comment: None of Viewdidload,Viewwillappear and viewdidappear of that controller gets called when it returns after authenticating. It only comes in fbdidLogin.

Comment: maintain flag in appdelegate when facebook login or logout. Now in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) method if flag true switch is on and vice-versa

Comment: Yup did that, thats the problem. Its not going in CellForRowAtIndexPath. I set a breakpoint there, but when application enters foreground, it just does not go to that method.

Comment: Post notification method when application enters foreground it will have logic [tableview reloadData];

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810105/giving-notification-to-another-class-with-nsnotificationcenter) link for notification

Comment: Its still not working for me.Thanks for the help. I'll post here if I find an answer.Any further help would be much appreciated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where u get access token for fb add post notification

**[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fbDidLogin" object:nil];**

Now the method for intial fb login is

```
-(void)fbLogin
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(fbDidLogin) name:@"fbDidLogin" object:nil];
 // some logic for intial fb login page
 }
```

Also in fbDidLogin method add this

```
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"fbDidLogin" object:nil]; 
[self.switch setOn:YES animated:YES];    
}
```

Here fbDIdLogin will be called as soon as access token is recieved

Similar process can be done for fb login failed if access token is nil .

Comment: Thats it.. !! Awesome. Exactly what I wanted.. Thanks a ton.